# How can I prevent an app from taking focus of my AirPods when I open it on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, music, ipados, airpods

Whenever I opened an app Pleco (Chinese-English dictionary app) while listening to music on YouTube (background mode), the music stopped playing. I manually have to play it again in order to listen to the music again. The app does not issue any sound unless I manually order it to do so, which I didn’t.

So is there any way to prevent the app from taking focus of my AirPods?